# driver=r8169 driverversion=6.5.0-21-generic not accepting I/G bit in MAC address assignment

Tags: networking, ethernet, realtek

I am trying to set a MAC address to my `RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller`, but the ID does not accept `xy:xx:xx:xx` when `y` is even. It seems the I/G bit (multicast) cannot be set.

Why is this happening?